# Getting wrong number of args passed to a Clojure function

Tags: clojure

More Clojure weirdness. I have this function I'm trying to define and call. It has 3 arguments, but when I call it with 3 arguments I get

```
Wrong number of args (1) passed to: solr-query$correct-doc-in-results-QMARK-$fn
 [Thrown class clojure.lang.ArityException]
```

when I call it with 2 arguments I get

```
Wrong number of args (2) passed to: solr-query$correct-doc-in-results-QMARK-
  [Thrown class clojure.lang.ArityException]
```

and when I call it with 4 arguments I get

```
Wrong number of args (4) passed to: solr-query$correct-doc-in-results-QMARK-
  [Thrown class clojure.lang.ArityException]
```

here is the definition of the function:

```
(defn correct-doc-in-results? [query results docid]
  "Check if the docid we expected is returned in the results"
  (some #(.equals docid) (map :id (get results query))))
```

and here is how I'm trying to call it (from the REPL using swank in emacs):

```
(correct-doc-in-results? "FLASHLIGHT" all-queries "60184")
```

anyone have any idea what's going on? Why does it think I'm only passing in 1 argument when I am passing 3, but gets it right for 2 or 4? I'm not a very fluent clojure programmer yet, but defining a function is pretty basic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note the difference between

`solr-query$correct-doc-in-results-QMARK-`

and

`solr-query$correct-doc-in-results-QMARK-$fn`

The first refers to your function `correct-doc-in-results?`.  The latter refers to some anonymous function defined inside that function.

If you pass 2 or 4 arguments, you're getting an error for your toplevel function, as expected.  When you pass 3 arguments, you're getting an error for `#(.equals docid)`, because `#(.equals docid)` wants zero arguments but is getting one.  Try changing it to `#(.equals % docid)`.

Comment: @Brian actually the error is because the anonymous function wants zero args (has no %) and is getting one when called by `some`. Of course, if the function actually *were* called with no arguments, then it would cause another error by trying to call `.equals` with only one argument.